# CAKEPHP CONDITIONS OR Statement

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to filter a search result based on the LIKE wildcard. I also want to add several OR statements if the end user inputs multiple keywords. But My query returns back all results instead of filter results, below is the code

```
        function search()
        {
            $queries = explode(" ", $this->data['Project']['query']);
            $nq = '';
            foreach($queries as $q)
            {
                $nq[] = array('Project.project_title LIKE'=>"%$q%");
            }

            $final = array("OR"=>$nq);

            debug($this->Project->find('list',$final));
        }



1   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `projects`       28  28  16
2   SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE COLLATION_NAME= 'latin1_swedish_ci';     1   1   1
3   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `users`      2   2   8
4   SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE COLLATION_NAME= 'utf8_general_ci';       1   1   1
5   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `categories`     6   6   11
6   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `operating_systems`      2   2   7
7   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `project_operating_systems`      3   3   10
8   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `projects_categories`        3   3   12
9   SELECT `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`project_title` FROM `projects` AS `Project` WHERE 1 = 1       4   4   1
10  SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name`, `Category`.`parent_id`, `Category`.`url`, `Category`.`lft`, `Category`.`rght`, `ParentCategory`.`id`, `ParentCategory`.`name`, `ParentCategory`.`parent_id`, `ParentCategory`.`url`, `ParentCategory`.`lft`, `ParentCategory`.`rght` FROM `categories` AS `Category` LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `ParentCategory` ON (`Category`.`parent_id` = `ParentCategory`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1
```

Comment: Please show the generated query. You can find it by setting the debug level to 2, the queries are shown in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
debug($this->Project->find('list',array('conditions'=>$final)));
```

Comment: This is helpful for debugging the issue, but is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

When building a query witn a series of `or`s like this, always be careful to enclose your `OR` conditions in parentheses, or you will negate your `AND` conditions.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE type='teacher'
```

Only gives you teachers.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE type='teacher'
AND name like '%Joe%'
```

This gives only teachers with "Joe" somewhere in their name. HOWEVER:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE type='teacher'
AND name like '%Joe%'
OR name like '%Mary%'
```

You might expect this to give teachers whose name is either "Joe" or "Mary"... but it does not. It will give you ANY user whose name is "Mary".  To correct this, you use parentheses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE type='teacher'
AND 
(name like '%Joe%'
OR name like '%Mary%')
```